# Popup provided by scanner driver does not offer a double-sided scan option

Tags: drivers, scanner

I am using a HP multifunction device to scan into a bespoke application for ongoing document storage. The application has generic TWAIN/WIA scanning interfaces - via TWAIN which appears to be the drivers allowed by this printer, it offers the choice of using its own UI to scan (which is a very simple screen which allows selection of only file format and DPI) or using the manufacturer's UI (which for most printers has more options, but for this printer literally only allows selecting between Glass and ADF scanning).

Is there any way to install some kind of alternate TWAIN driver to replace the manufacturer's scan UI supplied by HP, so that I can see more options on this screen?

Comment: Is it the driver or the "bespoke application" that is the issue? Have you spoken with the app developer?

Comment: Does the scanner actually have the hardware function to scan both sides? It has to be similar to what is required to be present inside a printer, to allow it to print on both sides.

Comment: It sure does, I have scanned multi side to USB - it just doesn't appear to offer this option from the UI.

Comment: I've now been able to install a different, better driver from the manufacturer when running over USB but it doesn't appear to work for scanning over Ethernet which is the next problem